# VBA: Problema al guardar archivo CSV desde Macro

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6, vbscript

Tengo los siguientes archivos:
    1- MAIN.xlsm
    2- Output.csv

En el archivo MAIN.xlsm tengo una macro que guarda y cierra el Output.csv. El problema está en que a la hora de guardar el archivo me lo guarda todo en una sola columna.

Código de macro saveOutput() en archivo MAIN.xlsm:

```
Sub SaveOutput()
    Workbooks("output.csv").SaveAs Filename:="output.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Workbooks("output.csv").Close saveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Archivo Output.csv antes de ser guardado:

[image: output ini]

Archivo Output.csv al abrirlo después:

[image: output fin]

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Te lo guarda como un archivo CSV separado por comas (por defecto VBA guarda con comas, formato americano) si tus fórmulas separan los argumentos con punto y coma te va a pasar que excel no sabe identificar la coma como separador. Como bien dice Roger, si pones `Local:=True` te lo guardará en formato local (punto y coma)

Comment: Es muy posible que sea justo lo que dice @rogerTorné. Si te fijas, al guardarlo ha cambiado el separador decimal de la coma por un punto, es decir, en formato anglosajón, en tus valores numéricos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por lo que veo en la imagen, la exportación es correcta. Obtienes un fichero de texto con las columnas separadas por comas. El problema lo tienes al abrirlo, puesto que no detecta las columnas.

Va a depender de quien deba usar este fichero. Si lo quieres utilizar con Excel, mejor utiliza las utilidades de importación. Pero puede que la solución más simple sea utilizar un separador distinto de la coma, por ejemplo el punto y coma, que es el habitual en los sistemas operativos con cultura no anglosajona. Para ello prueba utilizando el `local:=True`al exportarlo.

```
Workbooks("output.csv").SaveAs Filename:="output.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True
```

Comment: Ya he probado ese método pero me sigue yendo igual, también he cambiado el separador de windows y nada. Al final lo que he hecho es editar el documento csv desde un archivo batch, para que cambie la coma que quiero por un  ;    De todas formas, creo que tu respuesta le será útil a la gente que visite el post en el futuro, así que cuando pueda la marco como respuesta correcta :P. Gracias por vuestro tiempo

Answer (score -1):

Efectivamente, como dicen los compañeros tu código está funcionando correctamente sólo que no lo visualizas como tu quieres, otra opción que tienes para visualizarla de acuerdo a tus preferencias es seleccionar la columna entero y en el menú datos pinchar en texto en columnas y darle a delimitador coma y finalizar, de este modo, podrás comprobar que todo te funciona correctamente.
Por otra parte, en mi caso le estoy dando una vuelta de tuerca más a la propuesta de Roger y Damián ya que al colocar el siguiente código:

```
Workbooks("output.csv").SaveAs Filename:="output.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True
```

Lo guarda igualmente con `","` y nunca con `";"` independientemente de si en la propiedad local se le suministra el valor `True` o `False`, el resultado siempre es el mismo guarda el fichero con `","`.
javiertxu18, no sé si es a esto a lo que te referías en tu respuesta a Roger cuando dices que lo has probado y te sigue yendo igual.